# Clojure basics: counting frequencies

Tags: clojure

I am learning Clojure, and I saw this bit of code online:

```
(count (filter #{42} coll))
```

And it does, as stated, count occurrences of the number 42 in coll.  Is `#{42}` a function?  The Clojure documentation on filter says that it should be, since the snippet works as advertised.  I just have no idea how it works.  If someone could clarify this for me, that would be great.  My own solution to this same thing would have been:

```
(count (filter #(= %1 42) coll))
```

How come my filtering function has parenthesis and the snippet I found online has curly braces around the filtering function (`#(...)` vs. `#{...}`)?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249334/test-whether-a-list-contains-a-specific-value-in-clojure

Comment: No, I have not seen that answer.  I can see that they are also using similar bits of code.  There is also mention that `(#{x} x)` returns `x`.  I just don't get what `#{x}` is doing as a function.  Isn't that just a set?

Comment: See my answer. A set is not just a set - amongst other things it's an IFn so you can treat it as a function.

Comment: This is tangentially related, but in case you weren't aware, Clojure also has a function called [frequencies](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/frequencies) that is useful for cases like this. It produces a map of each item in a collection to the number of times it occurs. So you could do the above like this: `((frequencies coll) 42)` -- `(frequencies coll)` produces a map, which is used as a function to look up `42` and return the number of occurrences. (EDIT: To be fair, this is not as performant)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
=> #{42}
#{42}
```

Defines a set...

```
=> (type #{42})
clojure.lang.PersistentHashSet

=> (supers (type #{42}))
#{clojure.lang.IHashEq java.lang.Object clojure.lang.IFn ...}
```

Interestingly the set implements IFn so you can treat it like a function. The behaviour of the function is "if this item exists in the set, return it".

```
=> (#{2 3} 3)
3
=> (#{2 3} 4)
nil
```

Other collections such as map and vector stand in as functions in a similar fashion, retrieving by key or index as appropriate.

```
=> ({:x 23 :y 26} :y)
26
=> ([5 7 9] 1)
7
```

Sweet, no? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `#{42}` is a function,

- because it's a set, and sets, amongst other capabilities, are
  functions: they implement the `clojure.lang.IFn` interface.
- Applied to any value in the set, they return it; applied to anything
  else, they return `nil`.
- So `#{42}` tests whether its argument is `42` (only `nil` and `false` are false, remember).

The Clojure way is to make everything a function that might usefully be one:

- *Sets* work as a test for membership.
- *Maps* work as key lookup.
- *Vectors* work as index lookup.
- *Keywords* work as lookup in the map argument.

This

- often saves you a `get`,
- allows you, as in the question, to pass naked data structures to higher order functions
  such as `filter` and `map`, and
- in the case of keywords, allows you to move transparently between maps and records
  for holding your data.